# FFmpeg ProRes interlacing artifacts horrible compared to Apple Compressor export

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I've been importing my family videos recently. I'd like to archive these videos using ProRes 422.

Compressor works. The videos pop out with hardly ANY visual difference.

FFmpeg, however produces jagged shapes around moving objects. I don't know enough about video to describe what this actually looks like so I've included frames of what I'm seeing.

Original Video Frame
[image]

Compressor Video Frame:
[image]

FFmpeg Video Frame:
[image]

As you can see, the first two are indistinguishable. The last is was created using this: `ffmpeg -i original.mov -c:v prores -profile:v 2 output-ffmpeg.mov`

I have tried every single option for prores I can find. I've used `prores_ks`, `prores_aw`, the highest possible settings for bits/mb, etc. Nothing has worked to fix this.

Movement is pixelated. Anything that is remotely blurred becomes jagged lines.

How can I correct this in FFmpeg?

EDIT:

```
Here are the logs as requested
ffmpeg version 4.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.0 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-ffplay --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma --enable-libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=jpeg2000 --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/2.3.0/include/openjpeg-2.3 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fae4a800000] Duplicated ELST atom
    Last message repeated 1 times
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2006-10-07 16_06_44.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2018-04-12T23:08:23.000000Z
    com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
    com.apple.quicktime.model: MacBookPro10,1
    com.apple.quicktime.software: Mac OS X 10.13.4 (17E199)
    com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2018-04-12T17:02:55-0600
  Duration: 00:00:24.46, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 30510 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: dvvideo (dvc  / 0x20637664), yuv411p(smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709, bottom coded first (swapped)), 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], 16995 kb/s, SAR 10:11 DAR 15:11, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-04-12T23:08:23.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      encoder         : DV/DVCPRO - NTSC
      timecode        : 00:00:19;03
    Stream #0:1(und): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-04-12T23:08:23.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:19;03
    Stream #0:2(und): Audio: pcm_s16le (lpcm / 0x6D63706C), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-04-12T23:08:23.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (dvvideo (native) -> prores (native))
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mov, to 'output-ffmpeg.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2018-04-12T17:02:55-0600
    com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
    com.apple.quicktime.model: MacBookPro10,1
    com.apple.quicktime.software: Mac OS X 10.13.4 (17E199)
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: prores (apcn / 0x6E637061), yuv422p10le(bottom coded first (swapped)), 720x480 [SAR 10:11 DAR 15:11], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 0.03 fps, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-04-12T23:08:23.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:19;03
      encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 prores
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-04-12T23:08:23.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 aac
frame=  134 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=   17408kB time=00:00:04.17 bitrate=34191.1kbitsframe=  241 fps=238 q=-0.0 size=   34304kB time=00:00:07.99 bitrate=35168.5kbits[out_0_1 @ 0x7fae4b200f80] 100 buffers queued in out_0_1, something may be wrong.
[out_0_1 @ 0x7fae4b200f80] 1000 buffers queued in out_0_1, something may be wrong.
frame=  314 fps=208 q=-0.0 size=   45056kB time=00:00:10.29 bitrate=35853.6kbitsframe=  344 fps=171 q=-0.0 size=   48896kB time=00:00:11.17 bitrate=35834.8kbitsframe=  359 fps=143 q=-0.0 size=   51712kB time=00:00:11.97 bitrate=35361.1kbitsframe=  389 fps=129 q=-0.0 size=   56064kB time=00:00:12.85 bitrate=35728.5kbitsframe=  419 fps=119 q=-0.0 size=   60416kB time=00:00:13.70 bitrate=36105.2kbitsframe=  449 fps=112 q=-0.0 size=   64256kB time=00:00:14.68 bitrate=35854.0kbitsframe=  464 fps=103 q=-0.0 size=   67072kB time=00:00:15.47 bitrate=35497.6kbitsframe=  494 fps= 99 q=-0.0 size=   71424kB time=00:00:16.20 bitrate=36108.8kbitsframe=  524 fps= 95 q=-0.0 size=   75008kB time=00:00:17.18 bitrate=35758.3kbitsframe=  539 fps= 90 q=-0.0 size=   78336kB time=00:00:17.95 bitrate=35744.4kbitsframe=  569 fps= 87 q=-0.0 size=   82688kB time=00:00:18.93 bitrate=35774.7kbitsframe=  599 fps= 85 q=-0.0 size=   87040kB time=00:00:19.91 bitrate=35802.0kbitsframe=  629 fps= 84 q=-0.0 size=   91392kB time=00:00:20.81 bitrate=35973.7kbitsframe=  659 fps= 82 q=-0.0 size=   96000kB time=00:00:21.83 bitrate=36015.5kbitsframe=  689 fps= 81 q=-0.0 size=  100352kB time=00:00:22.81 bitrate=36029.0kbitsframe=  719 fps= 80 q=-0.0 size=  104704kB time=00:00:23.84 bitrate=35976.9kbitsframe=  732 fps= 79 q=-0.0 Lsize=  107993kB time=00:00:24.43 bitrate=36200.1kbits/s speed=2.62x    
video:107589kB audio:382kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.020916%
[aac @ 0x7fae49829000] Qavg: 243.907
```

Comment: Those are interlacing artifacts. Share the log output of `ffprobe original.mov`

Comment: @Gyan I have updated to post to include the logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
ffmpeg -i original.mov -vf yadif -c:v prores -profile:v 2 output-ffmpeg.mov
```

We may have to tweak it a bit depending on field order.